# Can't install pakages after installation of Ubuntu DDE on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I installed Ubuntu DDE on my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64.  But then I realized that I was unable to install some pakages on the machine. It seems to work on the Snap Store now but it didn't work there before. But I'm still unable to install pakages using Apt, resulting in some errors;

```
userdel: user 'deepin-anything-server' does not exist
Failed on delete user deepin-anything-server
dpkg: error processing package deepin-anything-server (--remove):
installed deepin-anything-server package post-removal script subprocess returne
d error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
deepin-anything-server
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Btw [this](https://codepre.com/how-to-install-deepin-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-20-10-or-20-04-linux-mint-20-x.html?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_imockU1tgCYY9km5LG4EivuLkJgPggORkquBL47lH1o-1630945469-0-gqNtZGzNAjujcnBszQf9), is the way i installed it. Removing it as the guide says does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily add a dummy `deepin-anything-server` userid to your system to satisfy the post-removal script with:

```
 sudo adduser --shell=/bin/false --no-create-home --disabled-login deepin-anything-server
```

Then rerun your command.

```
grep deepin /etc/passwd
```

to check

Comment: It worked! But it showed a different [error](https://pastebin.com/q5ZPfuQP). Do you maybe know a way to fix that?